# Match first instance of cell in a column not equal to the other column with offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Suppose I have the following table

```
    +---+-------+-------+
    |   |   A   |   B   |
    +---+-------+-------+
    | 1 |  7,75 |  9,50 |
    +---+-------+-------+
    | 2 |  9,50 | 10,50 |
    +---+-------+-------+
    | 3 | 10,50 | 11,50 |
    +---+-------+-------+
    | 4 | 11,75 | 13,00 |
    +---+-------+-------+
    | 5 | 13,00 | 14,00 |
    +---+-------+-------+
    | 6 | 14,00 | 15,25 |
    +---+-------+-------+
    | 7 | 15,25 |       |
    +---+-------+-------+
```

I want to find the first occurrence in column A where it does not match column B with an offset of -1 in the rows (in this case, it should give me `11.75`, `A4`)

I would like to avoid using `VBA`.

I tried using `MATCH`, but I'm unsure how to do the condition with 2 tables

Comment: so we ignore A1?

Comment: Indeed, A1 is ignored, else it would be pretty simple :P I can add it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would this work for you:

```
=LOOKUP(1,1/(A2:A7<>B1:B6),A2:A7)
```

No need to CSE `LOOKUP()`.

Comment: It will not return first occurrence in all cases

Comment: @JvdV what does the `1/(A2:A7<>B1:B6)` do ?

Comment: try by changing the values of two consecutive rows to different ones, for example change 13.00 to 13.50

Answer (score 3):

use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A2:A7)/(A2:A7<>B1:B6),1))
```

[image]

Comment: `=INDEX(A2:A7,MATCH(TRUE,B1:B6<>A2:A7,0))` should work too but it would need CSE'd depending on version.

Comment: Thank you ! I wasn't aware of `AGGREGATE` function. Time to look for the command in French !

Comment: @BigBen your solution wors too